# Cloudant geo load balancing - Is this enabled automatically?

Tags: haproxy, cloudant

I have been exploring cloudant and came across the following feature -

"Lower Database Latency – Users are connected with the closest replica by a geo load balancer to reduce the time database requests and responses travel."

I have two temporary cloudant accounts , say A and B with a "test" database. I have enabled both way replication between accounts for this database. Both accounts are hosted at different data centers.

With this setup, is the geo load balancing enabled by default ? If the data center for account A is not available, does my api request routed automatically to account B data center ?

Please note both accounts have separate API urls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to activate geo load balancing, an enterprise account is necessary. As of right now, multi-tenant accounts don't currently have the feature. (See here: https://cloudant.com/product-options/).

The alternative (on multi-tenant) would be for the customer to do it themselves with a DNS service or application logic.

Hope that helps.